# Databinding to a ListView inside a HubSection

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, data-binding, windows-phone-8.1

I'm getting search results from the Bing API and adding each article to List and trying to bind it to a ListView in XAML but no results appear in the HubSection.

```c#
private List<NewsArticle> bNews = new List<NewsArticle>();
```

where NewsArticle is defined as:

```
public class NewsArticle : INotifyPropertyChanged

{
     private string Description;
     public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
     public string Description1
     {
         get { return Description; }
         set { Description = value; }
     }

     private string Link;

     public string Link1
     {
         get { return Link; }
         set { Link = value; }
     }

     private string Title;

     public string Title1
     {
         get { return Title; }
         set { Title = value;
         NotifyProperyChanged("Title");
         }
     }

     public void NotifyProperyChanged(string propertyName)
     {
         if (PropertyChanged != null)
         {

             PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
         }
     }
```

And here is the XAML showing my HubSection and my bindings.

```xaml
<HubSection DataContext="{Binding bNews}" Name="newsHub" Header="Hello World">
                <DataTemplate>            
                    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="10" Name="ListBoxRss">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title1}" Tag="{Binding Link1}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                </DataTemplate>

            </HubSection>
```

I've looked around for other examples and was even able to get it to work properly in a Panorama style app but am having trouble getting it to work properly inside a HubSection. Any insight would be wonderful.